# Is there a way to generate sfdx auth url for scratch org if devhub is authorized using the jwt bearer flow?

Tags: jwt, salesforce, cicd, sfdx, salesforce-sfdx

In our CICD pipelines, we used to authorize devhub first using sfdx auth url and then create scratch orgs using same devhub. We use the command "sfdx force:org:display --verbose" to get the sfdx auth urls of the scratch orgs which we subsequently use for other CI processes in the pipeline. We thought of switching to JWT bearer flow to authorize devhub due to the frequent expiration of the refresh token which disrupts the pipelines.

We were successfully able to authorize the devhub using the JWT approach but after that on using "sfdx force:org:display --verbose" command, we are not able to get the sfdx auth url for the scratch org. I read and found that it is an expected behavior. Since all our pipelines are already set up, now authorizing scratch org with another approach would require a major pipeline design change. Is there any workaround to generate the sfdx auth url for the scratch orgs after authorizing devhub with JWT flow?

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_view_info.htm

but instead of using a `sfdx force:org:display -u my-scratch-org --verbose`

use a
`sfdx force:org:display -u username@scratchorg --verbose --json > ScratchOrgForceUrl.json`

which generate a forceUrl json which can use it to authorize using

```
sfdx auth:sfdxurl:store -f ScratchOrgForceUrl.json
```

Here is more in documentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_auth_sfdxurl.htm

Comment: As the OP stated, and as the documentation link references, this is not available with you are authenticated using the JWT flow.  There is no way to force it to generate an auth url in this context.  

@bikash_sb Were you able to find a solution to this?  I'm in the same situation, and I'm currently exploring using the use of `sfdx org login access-token` by taking the refresh token found in the JSON file and obtaining a valid access token when the CI/CD job executes.